# ADF Collaboration branch vs Publish branch

Tags: azure, azure-data-factory

In my ADF I have set publish branch to the same branch as my source branch using `publish_config.json`

I can now save and publish to a single branch without setting a collaboration branch (collaboration branch also is seen with a star). I can simple select my branch from the drop down in ADF and work on it. As such what is the use of a collaboration branch?

Answer (score 1):

The publish branch is just a place to store the generated ARM files for importing to another ADF.  You only need the ARM files when importing to another ADF.

Your collaboration branch is the only branch where you get the "publish" button.

The collaboration branch is different also from the others for being able to call ADF pipelines from logic apps or anything else external to ADF (after using the publish button).

Comment: could you please elaborate the third point? if publish is all about generating arm template then how is external apps coming into picture? Would publish also deploy to the ADF (raw) where we use git mode on?

Comment: also why does adf prompts as to publish before debugging or running?  after it is just creating arm templates with a publish